# CouchDB not connecting over SSL

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, couchdb

I installed CouchDB on an Ubuntu server on EC2 on AWS.

Then, I got an SSL cert with Let's Encrypt.

I edited the local.ini file to enabled SSL and point to the cert files.

I opened port 6984 on the EC2 instance.

I restarted CouchDB.

But, I still can't access it over SSL : (

Any help would rock!

Here's my curl

```
$ curl https://example.com:6984 -v
*   Trying ip.add.re.ss...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (ip.add.re.ss) port 6984 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /path/to/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /path/to/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to example.com:6984 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to example.com:6984
```

Some help would rock.